# How to set date in date input field of HTML using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, datefield

I am trying to set date in date type input filed using selenium in java with chrome browser but on submit, date filled is getting reset and filled validation message gets displayed.

Input field:

```
<input class="date_range_input" type="date" placeholder="Select Date" name="SelectDateFrom" min="2023-09-14" max="2023-09-20" value="">
```

Code:

```
Driver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

Tried solutions:

1.

```
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"input[name='SelectDateFrom']\").setAttribute('value', '2023-09-20')");
```

2. 

```
WebElement fromDateInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='SelectDateFrom']"));
fromDateInput.sendKey("2023-09-20");
fromDateInput.click();
```

Above solution able to set date in date field but when I submit form selenium code

```java
WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
submitButton.submit();
```

so the field **SelectDateFrom** gets reset and filed validation message shown

I want to set date in date input field of HTML using using selenium in java